# Meteor Crawler Able to click and analyze

Tags: meteor, web-scraping, web-crawler, phantomjs

New to meteor, new to crawlers. I am trying to build a small Meteor project which is able to crawl a website (multiple pages) and click elements before grabbing the data. From initial research all I find is a "headless browser" such as phantomjs. Not sure how well Phantom ties into Meteor. Has anyone used Meteor in this manner?

Comment: have a look http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/spiderable/

Comment: [Obviously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phantomjs+meteor)